# rootview controller in Interface builder?

Tags: iphone

i have done in didapplicationfinishing function

```
     tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init] ;
tabBarController.navigationItem.title = @"News";
SimpleTableViewController *rtbfViewController = [[SimpleTableViewController alloc]     
     init];
                                                 //initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
rtbfViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"News1";
rtbfViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];;
UINavigationController *table2NavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rtbfViewController] autorelease];
[rtbfViewController release];
```

**it works fine .suppose if i have Navigation controller in Interface Builder,how can i set initWithRootViewController in Interface builder?**

Answer (score 0):

Yep you can definitely accomplish this with Interface Builder.

1. Expand the Navigation Controller in Interface Builder and click on the View Controller (Root View Controller).
2. In the properties window first tab, change the XIB name to "SimpleTableViewController" and in the fourth tab set the class to "SimpleTableViewController."
3. Optionally, you can connect the SimpleTableViewController to an outlet on your class if you would like.

This sets the root view controller of the navigation controller to be your SimpleTableViewController.

Comment: I do not have the "View Controller" under the Navigation Controller. When I expand it I have two items: Navigation Bar and Navigation Item.